# How to draw a line inside a tablelayout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tablelayout

I am currently developing an android word search game. And I'm just learning Android Studio for almost a month now. I had made the ui of the game. Now my problem is the gameplay. I used a tablelayout for the textviews containing the letters for the puzzle.

Here is my createGrid() method for creating the tablelayout grid:

```
   public void createGrid(char[][] input){
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"kg.ttf");


    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        LinearLayout rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        rowLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        rowLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        for(int j = 0; j < input.length; j++){
            TextView text = new TextView(this);
            Character temp = input[i][j];
            text.setText(temp.toString());
            text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            text.setTextSize(25);
            text.setTypeface(font);
            text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            row.addView(text);
        }
        table.addView(row);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is make the tablelayout interactive by drawing a line when highlighting some letters.

I read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321178/android-drawing-a-line-to-follow-your-finger) that is all about the onDraw() and onTouchEvent() methods.

Now, I want to learn how to insert those codes on my program.

Or if that's impossible to do, any suggestions to help me improve this game?

Comment: @QBrute don't know what you're talking about mr?

Comment: from which point to which point to you want to draw that line?

Comment: @marmor from the start of the touch to where the finger stops the motion. I read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237004/unable-to-draw-line-over-gridview-elements-properly-through-textview-cells-in-an?noredirect=1&lq=1) but it features a gridview

Comment: well, it seems this is a duplicate of that question, it shouldn't matter that you're using a `TableLayout` and in that question it's a `GridView`, just use the part with `setOnTouchListener`, i.e. `table.setOnTouchListener(... );` and you'll probably want to use an xml layout for putting your `TableLayout` inside a `FrameLayout` like in his code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to draw line over gridview elements properly through textview cells in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237004/unable-to-draw-line-over-gridview-elements-properly-through-textview-cells-in-an)